# ValueError: cannot insert ID, already exists

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data:

```
ID   TIME
1    2
1    4
1    2
2    3
```

I want to group the data by `ID` and calculate the mean time and the size of each group.

```
ID   MEAN_TIME COUNT
1    2.67      3
2    3.00      1
```

If I run this code, then I get an error "ValueError: cannot insert ID, already exists":

```
result = df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'TIME': 'mean', 'ID': 'count'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Happened to me now and the below answers didn't work. But weirdly, upgrading my pandas from `1.0.5` to `1.1.1` worked! To upgrade, just do `pip upgrade pandas==1.1.1`

Comment: Happened to me with an empty (no rows) DataFrame.

Comment: Happened to me for pandas==2.0.0. I installed 1.4.4 to fix the issue

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use parameter `drop=True` which not create new column with `index` but remove it:

```
result = df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'TIME': 'mean', 'ID': 'count'}).reset_index(drop=True)
print (result)
   ID      TIME
0   3  2.666667
1   1  3.000000
```

But if need new column from index need `rename` old column names first:

```
result = df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'TIME': 'mean', 'ID': 'count'})
           .rename(columns={'ID':'COUNT','TIME':'MEAN_TIME'})
           .reset_index()
print (result)
   ID  COUNT  MEAN_TIME
0   1      3   2.666667
1   2      1   3.000000
```

Solution if need aggreagate by multiple columns:

```
result = df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'TIME':{'MEAN_TIME': 'mean'}, 'ID': {'COUNT': 'count'}})
result.columns = result.columns.droplevel(0)
print (result.reset_index())
   ID  COUNT  MEAN_TIME
0   1      3   2.666667
1   2      1   3.000000
```

Comment: Could you please explain what `drop=True` does?

Comment: @Dinosaurius instead of trying to incorporate the existing index back into the dataframe, it just drops it.

Comment: So, `new` will contain `ID`, while `ID` will be count, right? (in the second solution)

Comment: I think in this way is better second `piRSquared` solution if need only size of groups, not count `NaN` values in column `ID` - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pandas/1822/grouping-data/6874/aggregating-by-size-and-count#t=201701101917562920313)

Comment: @jezrael: yes, I don't have NaN values in the column `ID`.

Comment: Ok, then use another solution ;)

Answer (score 5):

I'd limit my `groupby` to just the `TIME` column.

```
df.groupby(['ID']).TIME.agg({'MEAN_TIME': 'mean', 'COUNT': 'count'}).reset_index()

   ID  MEAN_TIME  COUNT
0   1   2.666667      3
1   2   3.000000      1
```

Comment: Just curious: this solution allows only averaging by `TIME`? If I had more columns to average on, then this would need to be changed, right?

Comment: @Dinosaurius Yes!  You'd need to pass details in the dictionary passed to `agg` to account for the functions being applied to what columns and what to name the resultant columns.  It's best to ask for a specific result and we can help produce that result.

Answer (score 2):

You can also assign a copy of the grouping column prior to grouping:

```
df.assign(id_=df['ID']).groupby(['ID']).agg({'TIME': 'mean', 'id_': 'count'}).reset_index()
```