# Find maximum value in a 24 hour range, and pull all attributes for that row

Tags: python, pandas

I really need some help and have no idea how to go about this. I am fairly new to coding.

I have a year (2018) of hourly ozone, CO, wind, and temperature data for Calexico, CA in Imperial County and am trying to efficiently calculate the maximum daily 8-hour average (MDA8) of ozone for each day. I have replicated my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1-1-2018 00:00:00', '1-1-2018 01:00:00', '1-1-2018 02:00:00', '1-1-2018 03:00:00', '1-1-2018 04:00:00', '1-1-2018 05:00:00', '1-1-2018 06:00:00', '1-1-2018 07:00:00',
                                '1-1-2018 08:00:00', '1-1-2018 09:00:00', '1-1-2018 10:00:00', '1-1-2018 11:00:00', '1-1-2018 12:00:00', '1-1-2018 13:00:00', '1-1-2018 14:00:00', '1-1-2018 15:00:00',
                                '1-1-2018 16:00:00', '1-1-2018 17:00:00', '1-1-2018 18:00:00', '1-1-2018 19:00:00', '1-1-2018 20:00:00', '1-1-2018 21:00:00', '1-1-2018 22:00:00', '1-1-2018 23:00:00',
                                '1-2-2018 00:00:00', '1-2-2018 01:00:00', '1-2-2018 02:00:00', '1-2-2018 03:00:00', '1-2-2018 04:00:00', '1-2-2018 05:00:00', '1-2-2018 06:00:00', '1-2-2018 07:00:00',
                                '1-2-2018 08:00:00', '1-2-2018 09:00:00', '1-2-2018 10:00:00', '1-2-2018 11:00:00', '1-2-2018 12:00:00', '1-2-2018 13:00:00', '1-2-2018 14:00:00', '1-2-2018 15:00:00',
                                '1-2-2018 16:00:00', '1-2-2018 17:00:00', '1-2-2018 18:00:00', '1-2-2018 19:00:00', '1-2-2018 20:00:00', '1-2-2018 21:00:00', '1-2-2018 22:00:00', '1-2-2018 23:00:00'],
                   'ozone': [30.0, 32.1, 33.5, 33.7, 35.6, 34.8, 35.2, 36.1, 36.1, 36.3, 36.5, 37.2, 38.4, 39.9, 40.0, 42.1, 43.4, 42.5, 41.0, 40.0, 38.6, 36.6, 36.1, 36.6,
                             35.4, 33.0, 31.5, 32.6, 33.0, 33.8, 34.2, 35.1, 35.6, 36.2, 36.9, 37.5, 37.9, 38.3, 39.5, 40.5, 41.4, 42.8, 44.6, 44.0, 43.8, 42.1, 40.2, 39.9],
                   'temperature': [12.2, 12.2, 12.4, 12.1, 12.3, 12.5, 12.6, 12.8, 12.9, 13.1, 13.2, 13.4, 13.6, 13.7, 13.9, 13.9, 13.5, 13.2, 13.1, 13.1, 12.8, 12.8, 12.7, 12.7,
                                   12.6, 12.4, 12.4, 12.3, 12.1, 12.5, 12.7, 12.7, 12.9, 13.0, 13.0, 13.3, 13.5, 13.6, 13.8, 13.9, 14.0, 13.9, 13.7, 13.6, 13.4, 13.1, 12.9, 12.8],
                   'wind speed': [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.3, 2.3, 3.4, 3.4, 2.1, 3.6, 3.6, 3.5, 3.2, 3.1, 2.8, 2.7, 2.9, 2.4, 2.6, 2.4, 2.1, 2.5, 2.7, 2.3, 2.2, 
                                  2.5, 2.8, 2.5, 2.6, 2.4, 2.3, 5.1, 5.5, 5.2, 4.6, 4.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.4, 3.1, 3.5, 3.7, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.5, 3.4],
                   'CO': [0.33, 0.31, 0.31, 0.34, 0.35, 0.31, 0.31, 0.33, 0.30, 0.29, 0.28, 0.28, 0.27, 0.24, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.25, 0.21, 0.28, 0.31, 0.23, 0.31, 0.29,
                          0.33, 0.31, 0.31, 0.34, 0.35, 0.31, 0.31, 0.33, 0.30, 0.29, 0.28, 0.28, 0.27, 0.24, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.25, 0.21, 0.28, 0.31, 0.23, 0.31, 0.29]}, 
                  index=['date'])
```

I created a code that calculated the 8-hour rolling mean for ozone and found the daily maximum:

```
df['O3_mda8_3135'] = df.ozone.rolling('8H', min_periods=2).mean().shift(-4)
O3_mda8_3135 = df.groupby([date.month,date.day])['O3_mda8_3135'].max()
```

However, in my new dataframe, I also want the temperature, CO, and wind values **from the hour of the day that the ozone maximum occurs**. I am unsure how to do this. For a much smaller dataframe, I have tried:
`np.isclose(df['O3_mda8_3135'], #####).argmax()` but I cannot do this individually for every single day of the year, especially on the off chance that there are repeating values. Is there maybe some sort of loop code that I could try to pull the row of maximum ozone concentrations into a new dataframe and have 365 rows of ozone maximum daily 8-hour avg, CO, wind, and temperature?

I want the new dataframe to be:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1-1-2018 17:00:00', '1-2-2018 19:00:00'],
                    'ozone': [43.4, 44.6],
                    'temperature': [13.5, 13.7],
                    'wind speed': [2.4, 3.7],
                    'CO': [0.23, 0.21]})
```

based on the maximum values pulled from the ozone column, but showing the values for the corresponding datetime at that maximum value.

**UPDATE**: I found this function
`df.groupby([date.month, date.day])[O3_mda8_3135].idxmax(axis='columns')`
which gives me the datetime stamps of the maximum ozone values, however, it only shows me the time stamps and I want to extract all attributes from the corresponding row.

Comment: what is the structure of the dataframe you are using for this operation? It would be handy to know so that we can give you suggestions.

Comment: Hi, I just updated my post to include the format of my dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `idxmax()` (and `idxmin()`) method for GroupBy objects which can be used to return the index of the maximum within each group.  You can use this to index your original data:

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby([df['date'].dt.date])['O3_mda8_3135'].idxmax()]

                  date  ozone  temperature  wind speed    CO  O3_mda8_3135
16 2018-01-01 16:00:00   43.4         13.5         2.4  0.23       40.9375
42 2018-01-02 18:00:00   44.6         13.7         3.7  0.21       42.4250
```

The dates do not match the output you described, but I think these are correct?

Also I am doing the `groupby` by date using the `dt.date` attribute here instead of `dt.month` and `dt.day`.

Comment: Thank you, I found these functions right before I saw this. The only edit I had to make was resetting my index to a numeric index. The final code I used was ```O3_mda8_3135 = df.loc[df.reset_index().groupby([date.month, date.day])['O3_mda8_3135'].idxmax()]```

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate your data, or have a clear of your desired output because of the way you posted the question, but I think this the following code will take you closer to what you want:

The below code will potentially give you the daily `max()` value, and also get the columns you outlined in a new dataframe

```
O3_mda8_3135 = (df.groupby([date.month,date.day]).agg({'O3_mda8_3135':'max','TEMP_col':'first','CO_col':'first','WIND_col':'first'}).reset_index())
```

*Note that, 'TEMP_col', 'CO_col','WIND_col' that I have written there, should be replaced with the actual column names of your temperature / CO / wind columns respectively.*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I updated my question to be more specific. I tried what you suggested but keep getting an error message that says ```ValueError: cannot insert date, already exists``` but I did not include the date column in the .agg() portion. Also, my datetime is in the date column, which is not the index. Is that why I'm getting the error? I tried including the date column in the .agg() and renamed the column but get ```SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported```.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576242/valueerror-cannot-insert-id-already-exists I tried this but it did not help.

Comment: Also, the 'first' gives me the first value of those columns in that day. I need the values of those columns at the time at which the maximum value occurs. So in this example dataframe, the max value on 1/1 occurs at 5 pm, so I need the other values at 5 pm